# Why is a set a subspace only when its determinant is equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading in my book that a given set  ${(1,2,-1),(0,3,4),(0,2,1)} $ is a subspace of $R^n$ when the determinant does not equal zero of the coresponding table that set creates, like this :

\begin{array}{c c c} 
 1& 2 & -1  \\ 
 0& 3 & 4  \\ 
 0& 2 & 1  \\ 
 \end{array}

But why is that? What is the intuition behind that? doesn't $R^n$ include like everything ?

thank you.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion here. Firstly, no finite (nonzero) set will be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But the set of linear combinations of any subset of vectors will be a subspace. Having determinant zero is equivalent to the vectors being linearly dependent, so three linearly dependent vectors will span at most a proper subspace (meaning strictly smaller) than $R^3$.

Comment: I get that part but I can't understand why the determinant is so important in order to check if those vectors are a linear combination that determins whether they are a subspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *set* that you give is **not** a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It just consists of three single points (or vectors) if you prefer. However, the linear span of your set, i.e. the set of vectors that can be written as
$$ c_1 (1,2,-1) + c_2 (0,3,4) + c_3 (0,2,1) $$
is a subspace (here $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are arbitrary real numbers), and this hold regardless of which vectors you take. The determinant can be used as a quick test to see if the three vectors are linearly independent or not.

If the determinant is non-zero, the vectors are linearly independent, and they form a basis for the subspace they span. In this case, the subspace is the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If the determinant is zero, the vectors are linearly dependent, and they span a *proper* subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thank you. I get the mechanical part, but actually why? I can perform the operation blindly but I can't understand the reason why the determinant should play a role here

Comment: @themhz Geometrically, the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix measures the (signed) volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the columns (or rows) of the matrix. Hence, the determinant is $0$ if and only if the three vectors lie in the same plane which is the same as saying that they are linearly dependent.

Comment: that's my answer thank you!